# If statement inside create table query -Oracle-

Tags: oracle

I would like to create table which asks user input first. Then based on the input, it select which columns are added.

for example, if the response is 'N', then table is created including columns col1, col2, col3.
If the response is 'Y', table is created including columns col1, col2, col3, col4, col5.

Is this possible? 
If yes, please provide me simple and primitive query so that I can apply it to my case.

Thanks,

Comment: You can't have conditional logic in a `CREATE TABLE` statement.  You could write a small script in whatever client-side language you'd like that asks the user for input and creates one of two DDL statements in response.

Comment: why not? with dynamic SQL he can. create a little function and you can create an if statement where you decide by the input which DDL will you use

Comment: @Thomas - That's not logic in a `CREATE TABLE` statement.  That's logic that is wrapped around two separate potential `CREATE TABLE` statements.  You'd still need a small script to prompt the user for input and then call the function (you could use a `SQL*Plus` script for this, that's just one of the client scripting languages that you could use).

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL*Plus it's simple:

```
ACCEPT table_option -
PROMPT 'Create more columns? '

SET TERM OFF
COLUMN extra_columns NEW_VALUE extra_columns
SELECT
    CASE '&table_option'
        WHEN 'Y' THEN ', C4 NUMBER, C5 VARCHAR2(255), C6 DATE'
    END extra_columns FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE tmp (
    C1 NUMBER,
    C2 VARCHAR2(255),
    C3 DATE &extra_columns
);

SET TERM ON
```

You can store the script as a file and invoke it from SQL*Plus using @filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp_custom_DDL( p_input  VARCHAR2 IN, p_resp CHAR IN OUT)  RETURN CHAR
AS

v_str    VARCHAR2(4000);

IF p_resp = 'Y' THEN 

v_str := 'col1 varchar2(10), col2 varchar2(10), col3 varchar2(10)';

ELSE v_str := 'col1 varchar2(10), col2 varchar2(10), col3 varchar2(10), col4 varchar2(10), col4 varchar2(10) ' ; 

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_comm_1  || v_str  || v_comm2;
--v_comm_1  is the first half of create table command till the specified cols
--v_comm_2 is the rest of the create table command


RETURN p_resp;

END;
```

this is only a quick draft, fix the few lexical bug and the missing definitions :)  (this is the first step)